# No user to login in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: login, high-sierra

I installed macOS High Sierra updating to APFS and everything was working correctly. After a couple of days I shut down and went off. I just came back and when I boot there are no users to login as usual, I get a Name and Password fields.

Of course my user is not working and it is not the usual login where your user is the one you see and just type your password.

So I have a Name and Password fields that I can’t fill with anything, so I can’t login to my user.

In recovery mode I ran First Aid and I get:

```
The volume /dev/rdisk3s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.
File system verify or repair failed.
Operation failed...
```

Anyone with the same problem? Any advice or solution for this?

Comment: Yah, this is a *developer* (not public) beta and these kinds of errors (errors that trash the system or your access to it) are just going to happen. Hopefully you made a backup before installing the beta. Unless there are Apple specific developer discussion boards that you could ask about this I would just wipe and re-install.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a developer beta

Comment: I'd leave it open as a lesson in what backups are for & why not to run betas on mission-critical machines.

Comment: Yes, it is a Developer beta. Yes, I have a backup. Yes, I will try to fix before formatting, that’s why I am asking to see if someone knows a terminal command to force my user to be used to boot. It seems not.

Comment: To have included that information in your original question would probably have garnered more useful comments & answers, & reduced the number of close votes & downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and it is a simple fix.

1. restart your computer
2. when it "chimes" hold down "command" and "R" until a menu pops up.
3. Go to "Utilities" at the top of the page menu bar
4. Go to "terminal"
5. In the terminal type "resetpassword"
6. Follow the instructions. You may need you Apple ID. My Administrator account does not have an Apple ID, so I just reset the Administrator password without needing an Apple ID.

If you are not able to sign in with other accounts on your computer, go to your administrator account and make sure to uncheck **Enable parental controls** for those accounts in under **System Preferences - Users and Groups.** Then the other accounts should work fine.

Comment: You are a amazing.  Thank you so much for this answer.  I was googling my way to glory and was unable to fix this for hours.  This was the fix.  Thanks again!